# How to quantify the "decreasingness" of a list

Tags: descriptive-statistics, ranking, distance, spearman-rho

Since I am unable to come up with a satisfying definition, let "decreasingness" be defined by the following example:

Suppose we have the following three lists:

$x_1 = (3, 2, 1),\ x_2 = (3, 4, 1)$, and $x_3 = (4, 2, 1)$.

How can we quantify the "decreasingness" of these three lists so that $x_3$ is preferred over $x_1$, and $x_1$ is preferred over $x_2$?

Comment: Some metric on permutations ? Maybe the smallesy number of swaps to reach 4,3,2,1 ?

Comment: How about an inter-list comparison of lags between consecutive elements of the list?

Comment: This question is fairly unclear. Are the same objects in each of the *x*'s in the same positional order with the difference being the method by which they are ranked? Next is it your objective that the preference structure described (*x3*>*x1*>*x2*) is recovered? If not and an empirical solution is allowed then why not use PCA on these metrics and rank the preference structure based on the magnitude of the loadings for the first component?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities, to choose between then we would need to know about your use case. One simple idea is to find the least number of swaps needed to map, say (1,3,2) to (3,2,1), which in this case is two: $(1,3,2) \mapsto (2,3,1) \mapsto (3,2,1)$. First we swap the first with the last element, then the first and second.

For more possibilities, think about rank correlations and compute the rank correlation between your ranking and the completely decreasing ranking. One paper discussing such ideas is http://theory.stanford.edu/~sergei/papers/www10-metrics.pdf  There is much more information to be found in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780444520876500111

Comment: Rank correlations distinguish between configurations like (#1 and #3) for which rank correlation with (3, 2, 1) is 1 and #2 for which it isn't. If you want to make it quantitative among monotonic sequences, first element $-$ last element or first/last could work with the examples, But this has to be bounced back with a request be to more precise. For example, are data necessarily positive? And so forth.